# White bar bottom of webpage? Creating first site, from scratch for upcoming trip.

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could help with a problem I'm having on the site I'm creating for my upcoming travel plans.  I have been following a Udemy web coding class, and know the basics of html, and css.  Enough to make this website.  If there's any tips or constructive criticism on my code I'd greatly appreciate it.

http://www.daltoninjapan.com is the live site.  It seems to be at the bottom of all three pages and I think it might have something to do with either a Script, or my "TOP" button.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but what do you want us to do here? What seems to be at the bottom of all three pages?

Comment: if you are looking for feedback on your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for it. If you are stuck at any point, feel free to ask here. Also do look at our [what topics are allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guide.

Comment: The bars in question seems to be missing now after looking at my files... Strange, but I appreciate the help, and patience.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is poorly structured, but I think I deciphered what do you want to do. Instead of:

```
#topbutton {
    float:right;
    align:bottom-right;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:10px 10px 40px 10px;
}
```

use this

```
#topbutton {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:10px 10px 40px 10px;
}
```

`position:fixed` will ensure that element is always at the same position and it takes the element out of flow. You can learn more about element positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Comment: You're missing the "position: relative" for #container for this to work.

Comment: I've tried it directly on the page and it works @Goombah

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appreciate the patience and helpful answer!  You knew what I meant after all.